# Use a c# Func as part of an IQueryable without executing into memory call

Tags: c#, linq, func

I'm trying to build a query that will execute against the database as an IQueryable, and not in memory (IEnumerable).

The query will be used for several different purposes and each purpose has a slightly different way in which the Total property is calculated.

Because I'm using a Func for calculating the total, i get an error advising me that sql doesn't know how to deal with the Invoke method of my Func, which is understandable.

To get past the problem, i have had to list the groupings into memor by calling ToList() which is not good for performance.

Is there a way that i can execute this query as an IQueryable? Otherwise im going to have to write this query 20+ times with a  calculation variance

```
Func<IGrouping<object, MyType>, double?> calculateTotal= (group) => @group.Sum(x => x.PassengerTotal);

Dictionary<object, double?> weekValues = queryable.GroupBy(o => new
               {
                   Year = SqlFunctions.DatePart("yyyy", o.DateCreated),
                   Week = SqlFunctions.DatePart("ww", o.DateCreated),
                   Source = o.SourceId,
               })
               .ToList() //NEED TO REMOVE THIS CALL
               .Select(ac => new WeeklyGraphGroup()
               {
                   Year = ac.Key.Year,
                   Week = ac.Key.Week,
                   SourceId = ac.Key.Source,
                   Total = calculateTotal(ac)
               })
               .ToDictionary(dict =>
                   new
                   {
                       Year = dict.Year,
                       Week = dict.Week,
                       Source = dict.SourceId
                   }, grp => grp.Total);
```

Comment: Take a look at [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx).

Comment: Instead of `Func<...>` you need to implement `calculateTotal` as `Expression<Func<...>>` and then use LinqKit or similar to embed it inside your query `Select` as @Yacoub suggested.

Comment: Why do you say "which is not good for performance"? In my experience it can be much faster to bring things in to memory. Did you do anything to try measure if it would be faster?

Answer (score 1):

Create a partial class as follows:

```
public partial class WeeklyGraphGroup
{
    public int ? Year { get; set; }

    public int  ? Week { get; set; }

    public int Source { get; set; }

}

public partial class WeeklyGraphGroup
{
    private int ? _Total;

    public int ? Total
    {


        get
        {


            this._Total = CalculateTotal(this.Year, this.Week, this.Source);

            return this._Total;
        }

    }

    public int ? CalculateTotal(int ? Year, int ? Week, int Source)
    {

        // do your calculation and return the value of total
        // use whatever formula you want here. I guess you are calculating 
        // total based on any of the parameters(year, week or source);

        return value;

    }



}
```

Then do your query as below:

```
var list = db.Stores.GroupBy(o => new WeeklyGraphGroup
{
Year = SqlFunctions.DatePart("yyyy", o.DateCreated),
Week = SqlFunctions.DatePart("ww", o.DateCreated),
Source = o.SourceId,
})
.Select ( u => new WeeklyGraphGroup 
{
Year = u.Key.Year,
Week = u.Key.Week,
Source = u.Key.Source
}
).ToList();
```

Total will be updated automatically